# Translate "I'm done" in Spanish

Tags: traducción

How would one say "I'm done" (in the sense of "I am finished with whatever I was doing until now" or "I'm free now") in Spanish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say it in different ways:

```
¡Listo!
Ya terminé (de hacer lo que estaba haciendo)
Ya acabé  (de hacer lo que estaba haciendo)
No tengo nada que hacer ahora (I'm free now)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use "haber + participle" instead of preterite.

```
"Ya he terminado" = "I'm done"

"Ya estoy disponible" = "I'm free now" (where "free" = "available")
```

Answer (score 1):

At Colombia the expressiohn **Hasta aqui llego!** is the exact translation of *I'm Done!* .